# Fade in and Fade Out multiple Images automatically

Tags: ios, uiimageview, fade

I am hew here and need help.
I work with storyboard and want make a automatically fade in fade out photo show.
The problem is that i have 10 images and don't now how to make this Programmatically.
I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 3):

```
  mainImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    NSArray *animationArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"third.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"fourth.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"fifth.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"sixth.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"seventh.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"eight.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"nine.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"ten.png"], nil]; //add your images here
                               [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(crossfade) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [mainImageView  setFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,100,100)];
                               mainImageView.animationImages = animationArray; //mainImageView is   imageview
                               mainImageView.animationDuration = 10;
                               mainImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
                               [mainImageView startAnimating];


     [self.view addSubview:mainImageView];


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)crossfade {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                                       mainImageView.alpha = !mainImageView.alpha;
                                   }completion:^(BOOL done){
                                    //
                }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quickly help. I have only one Problem that the images are not synchronized when he make animation

Comment: for 10 images set animationduration to be 7.5..since the time interval is of .75 duration

Comment: and by animateWithDuration? in der -(void)crossfade?

Comment: Check the updated code ..it gives animation fade out/in for ten images

Comment: +1 This works incredibly! The Duration stuff is a little messed up but it's an easy fix if you change the NSTimerCode and always make sure the NSTimer duration is equal to the sum of these two numbers: `animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0` ... God bless!

Comment: This has driven me crazy the out of sync I have 9 images I want each image to fade from 1 to the other every 5 seconds using the above code...anyone can help?